# SwiftUI: detecting the NavigationView back button press

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In `SwiftUI` I couldn't find a way to detect when the user taps on the default back button of the navigation view when I am inside `DetailView1` in this code:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @State private var showDetails: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView1(), isActive: $showDetails) {
                    Text("show DetailView1")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("RootView")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView1: View {
    @State private var showDetails: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView2(), isActive: $showDetails) {
            Text("show DetailView2")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("DetailView1")
    }
}

struct DetailView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("")
            .navigationBarTitle("DetailView2")
    }
}
```

Using `.onDisappear` doesn't solve the problem as its closure is called when the view is popped off or a new view is pushed.

Comment: What would you like to do after you detect it? When the user taps the Back button, your DetailView1 view will be dismissed and your showDetails state variable will reset to false – maybe this is key you are looking for?

Comment: `showDetails` changed back to false after `.onDisappear`, not before, so it cannot be used for early back button tap detection. Just in case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The quick solution is to create a custom back button because right now the framework have not this possibility.

```
struct DetailView : View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body : some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action : {
                self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }){
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm this way. I wanted to save some form values when user pressed "back" button. This way works fine. I only want to little update design things. Use "chevron.left", not "arrow.left" symbol. ` HStack {  Image(systemName:"chevron.left") Text("Back").font(.body)
}
`

Comment: this is the best solution, as you can also execute code _before_ dismissing the view

Comment: If you're using this solution, you might also want to make sure that your action runs if the user swipes to go back (instead of tapping the Back button).

Comment: NB. navigationBarItems(leading:) is not supported on macOS.

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham Good point; I never swipe like that. Can that behavior be disabled? This has been a problem for years with slider controls in UIKit, where the page will swipe instead of the control moving.

Answer (score 12):

As soon as you press the back button, the view sets isPresented to false, so you can use an observer on that value to trigger code when the back button is pressed. Assume this view is presented inside a navigation controller:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.isPresented) var isPresented

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().onChange(of: isPresented) { newValue in
            if !newValue {
                print("detail view is dismissed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only on >= iOS 15

Comment: Whether you push a new view onto the stack, or pop the current one, `isPresnted` will become false, so this answer only works when DetailView is the last view in a navigation stack.
OP's question explicitly mentions that they cannot use `.onDisappear` because of the same problem.

Comment: If you try to swipe back and cancel it will fire `false`. But if you swipe back again `onChange` will not be triggered again. This is a sketchy solution.

Answer (score 2):

An even nicer (SwiftUI-ier?) way of observing the published `showDetails` property:

```
struct RootView: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var showDetails = false
    }
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView1(), isActive: $viewModel.showDetails) {
                    Text("show DetailView1")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("RootView")
            .onReceive(self.viewModel.$showDetails) { isShowing in
                debugPrint(isShowing)
                // Maybe do something here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `onReceive` closure is called with `isShowing = false` in both cases: (1) when I pop the view to the root view. (2) when I go to `DetailView2`. so this solution doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment, I would react to changes in the state of `showDetails`. Unfortunately `didSet` doesn't appear to trigger with `@State` variables. Instead, we can use an observable view model to hold the state, which does allow us to do intercept changes with `didSet`.

```
struct RootView: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var showDetails = false {
            didSet {
                debugPrint(showDetails)
                // Maybe do something here?
            }
        }
    }
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView1(), isActive: $viewModel.showDetails) {
                    Text("show DetailView1")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("RootView")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use .onDisappear, if using NavigationView -> NavigationLink to detect event on press back button

Answer (score 1):

@93sauu’s approach is the way. But a commenter correctly pointed out that this will result in swipe to back to not function. The correction to this is to drop this extension:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

On iOS 17 at least, this worked with no issues.