# Reloading Previous View from Navbar

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have been following a tutorial on creating a weather app. I am trying to take it further. When on the weather view the user can click a plus button which takes them to a location view. Here the user will be able to update the location then when going back the weather will reload. But i am really struggling to get the weather to reload when pressing the back button.

Below is my code for the WeatherView & LocationView

Thank you

```
 struct WeatherView: View {
@State private var isShowing = false
@State var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60
@State var x = -UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 60
@ObservedObject var input = CityId()
let heptics = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
@ObservedObject var weatherViewModel = WeatherViewModel()


var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
                    ZStack {
                        BackgroundView()
                        
                        VStack {
                            if weatherViewModel.stateView  == .loading {
                                ActivityIndicatorView(isAnimating: true).configure {
                                    $0.color = .white
                                }
                            }
                            
                            if weatherViewModel.stateView  == .success {
                           
                                LocationAndTemperatureHeaderView(data: weatherViewModel.currentWeather)
                                Spacer()

                                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                                    VStack {
                                        
                                        DailyWeatherCellView(data: weatherViewModel.todayWeather)
                                        Rectangle().frame(height: CGFloat(1))

                                        HourlyWeatherView(data: weatherViewModel.hourlyWeathers)
                                        Rectangle().frame(height: CGFloat(1))

                                        DailyWeatherView(data: weatherViewModel.dailyWeathers)
                                        Rectangle().frame(height: CGFloat(1))

                                        Text(weatherViewModel.currentDescription)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                            .padding(
                                                .init(arrayLiteral:.leading,.trailing),
                                                24
                                            )
                                        Rectangle().frame(height: CGFloat(1))

                                        DetailsCurrentWeatherView(data: weatherViewModel.currentWeather)
                                        Rectangle().frame(height: CGFloat(1))

                                    }
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            if weatherViewModel.stateView == .failed {
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.weatherViewModel.retry()
                                }) {
                                    Text("Failed get data, retry?")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.colorScheme(.dark)
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: LocationView(input: input, weatherViewModel: weatherViewModel), isActive: $isShowing) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            ) // End of Background
                    .navigationBarTitle((input.score), displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                    Button(action: {
                        isShowing = true
                        heptics.impactOccurred()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                } // End of ToolbarItem
            } // End of Toolbar
        } // End of Nav View
} // End of body
```

} // End of View

```
struct LocationView: View {
@ObservedObject var input: CityId
@ObservedObject var weatherViewModel: WeatherViewModel
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
var body: some View {
    
    Button(action: {
        input.score = "2643743"
        weatherViewModel.stateView = .loading
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: detecting the NavigationView back button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930915/swiftui-detecting-the-navigationview-back-button-press)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider adding .onAppear modifier to your first view then you can update the data.

Comment: Hi thnaks for yuor reply. the problem is when the Back button is pressed in a navigation view the view does not load the onAppear. If that makes sense.